# Logout issue in google+ integration in android app

Tags: java, android

I have integrated google+ in my android app, it connects with google+ and takes information, but when logging out it is logging in automatically. I found that while checking the condition `googleApiClient.isConnected()` before logout it returns `false`. How to solve this?

```
private void gPlusSignIn() {
    if (!googleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
        Log.d("user connected","connected");
        isSignInBtnClicked = true;
        progressDialog.show(thisActivity, "Please Wait",
                "Loading...", true);
        resolveSignInError();
    }
}


private void resolveSignInError() {
    if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
        try {
            isIntentInProgress = true;
            connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(thisActivity, SIGN_IN_CODE);
            Log.d("resolve error", "sign in error resolved");
        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
            isIntentInProgress = false;
            googleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }
}


public static void gPlusSignOut() {
    if (googleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(googleApiClient);
        googleApiClient.disconnect();
        isSignInBtnClicked = false;
        Log.d("user Disconnected","Disconnected");
       //  googleApiClient.connect();
      //  changeUI(false);
    }
}
```